# R Shiny - how to run a function with reactives just before session ends

Tags: r, shiny

How can I run a function that depends on reactive values just before the session ends?

If I try using 'onStop' it doesn't work, see code below.  Start the app, it loads a reactive value - how can this reactive value be used when ending the session?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  v <- reactiveValues(user = NULL)  # define the reactive value
  v$user <- "test_user" # populate the reactive value
  observe(cat(v$user)) # print the reactive value to console

  onStop(function(){
    cat(v$user) # this doesn't work - it errors when exiting the session
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try using `isolate` such as `cat(isolate(v$user))` to access a reactive value in a non-reactive context.

Comment: You could use `onSessionEnded`? It will run that function just before the session ends. It doesn't matter *how* the session ends, e.g. user closes browser window etc.

Comment: Comparing onStop and onSessionEnded - I've found onSessionEnded tends to work more often but sometimes neither of them trigger.

Comment: onStop() and onSessionEnded() are not well documented. They confuse the hell out of me. If anyone on this answer thread are familiar with them quite well or have found another question that addresses them well please post a link. The current question is as clear as crytal but alas no answers.

Comment: BTW `isolate()` worked. But I am still not clear between the difference of `onStop()` and `onSessionEnded()`